# Java sockets: open connections from server to client

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty, nio

I have a client server problem with the following unique requirement:
1. The server has to open N connections to the known client and the client can only use those connections to request data from the server.

So far I tried to do the following but ran into some issues:

1. Have a socket listener on the client and have it enqueue each connection received into a ArrayBlockingQueue.
2. Client app will use connections available in the queue above to request data from server
3. I create one thread(worker) per socket on the server and listen for data requests through N worker threads.
4. when I wait for incoming requests in the worker threads(on sever) I use InputStream.isAvailable() to check if there is something waiting to be read.

Issue: the worker threads on the sever side don't know if socket connection is still live or not? They continue to listen for requests even after the sockets are closed on the client app.

How can I make my server sense if the socket connection is still live or not ?

Am I taking the right approach here?

Is there a framework out there which will make the implementation easier and better ?

Comment: Send a message to the server on close. Alternatively make all connections timeout after a certain level of inactivity? I believe this happens automatically but you can set an explicit timeout as well.

Comment: The issue you cite doesn't exist. The server will read EOS when the client closes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just reverse the protocol?

- Your clients will initiate the connection
- Your server will authorize them (allowing only the known clients)
- Then your server can receive/push the data to the clients, and receive the acknowledgements
- If the connection is lost, the client can reinitiate (the server can keep track what data has been sent to each client, and resend the missed data on reconnect)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, it is a requirement(security) that only server should initiate the connections.

Comment: @user851894 That's a totally bad idea, but that's the usual story with all requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged the question with netty. Have you tried using Netty? In either case I would recommend it.

- Your client should use a ServerBootstrap/ServerSocketFactory and an appropriate channel pipeline. Netty already has a ChannelGroup concept that could be used instead of the BlockingQueue. Your client code can find a free channel by iterating over the group and remove a free channel (and putting it back when done). A channel group also automatically detects closed channels and removes them from itself.
- Your server would use a ClientBootstrap/ClientSocketFactory and an appropriate channel pipeline with a handler that responds to client requests.
- Normal TCP close operations will be detected and the channel will be closed. If your are concerned that clients "crash" and leaves the other end in limbo, Netty has an IdleStateHandler that can close the channel after a certain period of inactivity

Comment: I took a quick look but wasn't sure how to use it for my use case.  I will try it and let you know. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue: the worker threads on the sever side don't know if socket connection is still live or not?

Yes they do. They will read an EOS when the client closes the connection. No issue there.

> They continue to listen for requests even after the sockets are closed on the client app.

Only if you have ignored the EOS condition.

> How can I make my server sense if the socket connection is still live or not ?

If you get EOS when reading, close the socket and stop the read loop.

> Am I taking the right approach here?

Your problem description is back to front. It is clients that create connections to servers, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. 1. Using just isAvailable() it is not possible to sense a disconnect. Yes, if I read I will be able to sense it. Based on your suggestion, should I be reading byte by byte ?                    2. Unfortunately my requirement(security) is that  only the server should initiate connections. If it wasn't for this one requirement, it would be really straightforward to solve.

Comment: You should just read when you need to read and handle EOS when it arises. available() is not an EOS test and has few other valid uses. Your requirement is misusing standard terminology. Your server is a client and your clients are servers from the TCP point of view.

Comment: Right,up until the connection is established the roles of server and client is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

> when I wait for incoming requests in the worker threads(on sever) I use InputStream.isAvailable() to check if there is something waiting to be read.

`InputStream.isAvailable()` never tells if the connection has been closed by the peer.  You must call `read()` to check if the connection has been closed.

If you must use `InputStream.isAvailable()`, you must at least write something periodically to the `OutputStream`, then you will get an `IOException` that indicates that the connection has been closed (`connection reset by peer` for example).

Comment: Right, how about having a HeartBeatSender on my client and a worker thread (HeartBeatListener) dedicated for listening to heartbeats? If I don't get heartbeat for sometime, I can then reset N worker threads with new socket connections.